# How many normal planes?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a surface $S$, a point $p$ on the surface, and the unit normal vector $\vec{N}$ passing through $p$ on the surface.

There are infinitely normal planes passing $p$ and its unit normal vector $\vec{N}$ to the surface $S$ at $p$, right? I am considering the case where $S$ is a two-dimensional surface embedded in 3-dimension. But this statement is still generally true for arbitrary $n$-dimensional surface embedded in $m$-dimension, where $n<m$ - right?

Thanks~

Comment: Your question/statement is ambiguous.

Comment: oh, sorry - let me modify.

Comment: By a "normal plane at $p$" you might mean a plane in space which makes a 90 degree angle with the tangent plane at $p$. If so, any plane containing $p$ and the normal vector $N$ will be such a "normal plane at $p$", and your statement is right that there are infinitely many such normal planes. I haven't seen this definition of normal plane used much, however it's an interesting idea. +1 on question...